# Getting https HTML Content Using Java

Tags: java, ssl

So I'm currently trying to read through my own https html page that uses a Comodo RSA Domain Validation certificate using TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_128_GCM, using Java. I've narrowed down my problem to simply being that the certificate isn't being accepted by Java Security because other websites such as Google work. Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(verURL);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        return line;
    }
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

I know that I need to relax the security to accept the certificate and be able to proceed, however, my question is why? Specifically, why is the Comodo (a reputable security company) certificate considered unsafe by Java Security so much so that it requires additional coding to prevent errors? Or is it possible that it's because the certificate is only a domain validation certificate?

---

Below you will find the error message for those curious:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at REDACTED(REDACTED.java:19)
at REDACTED(REDACTED.java:215)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 20 more
```

Comment: The CA certificate is not included in Java's rather sparse root certificate keychain.  You have to add it yourself.

Comment: @JimGarrison Does Java doing it like that have any security benefits? For example, a change of a download URL to something not included would result in an error providing increased software reliability when performing updates or other downloads.

Comment: They just don't include a large set of root CA certificates.  I remember reading somewhere recently that the situation is improved in Java 9, but can't find the reference right now.

Comment: @JimGarrison That makes sense. Thanks for the answer and happy new year.

Comment: It is unlikely that the root CA is missing, see https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/296/17/are-your-roots-included-in-any-java-release. It is more likely that the server setup is broken and is not serving a required intermediate CA. Desktop browsers usually work around such broken setups, other clients don't. Check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for incomplete chain or similar problems. Other problems might be missing but required SNI extension depending on what kind of Java version you are using.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich An SSL report of the website produced a rating of 'B' and an incomplete certificate chain. Additionally, the site only works with browsers that have SNI support. DNS CAA (Certificate #1): No. Both certificate paths required extra downloads after being sent from the server. java 7u25 and up work, java 6u45 and down are incompatible because the client does not support DH parameters > 1024. Everything else reported no errors.

Comment: @arkdevelopment: *"..incomplete certificate chain...Both certificate paths required extra downloads after being sent from the server* - this describes what I've assumed, i.e. the servers configuration is broken and because of this your application is failing.